# Deleting empty spool file when no data

Tags: sql, linux, oracle11g, sql-scripts

I have a sql script which creates a spool file.

When I do not have data, I am getting an empty file created. I do not want the file to get created in that case.

How can I do this?

```
set termout off;
set newpage 0;
set space 0;
set linesize 255;
set pagesize 0;
set echo off;
set feedback off;
set heading off;
set verify off;
set trimspool on;



UNDEFINE p_xml_filename


DEFINE p_xml_filename=&1

spool &p_xml_filename

SELECT * FROM emp;

spool off;
set feedback on
set verify on
set heading on
set echo on
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling it in **SQL*Plus**, I would rather do it at **OS level**. In your scenario, you want to spool the file only if data exists. But, to do that, you need to check the **COUNT** of rows in the table, thus it is an overhead to the process.

Alternatively, I would:

- Let the spool happen always
- Do a **grep** of the spool file to check the content
- **Remove** the file if no content found. `rm filename`

Comment: Thanks ...This works but instead of using grep I put this condition if [ -s "$exportFileName" ]
then
 echo "$exportFileName has some data."
        # do something as file has data
else
 echo "$exportFileName is empty."
        rm  $exportFileName
fi

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, you could do that too.